# What should be the size of an icon showed on the browsing screen on app store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icons, app-store

I have successfully submitted and got approved my app in the app store. Now the problem I'm facing is my app icon has very low and blurry quality on the apps browsing screen on the app store. I have prepared and uploaded crisp and sharp PNG icon images with app binary:

Icon.png (57 x 57)
Icon@2x.png (114 x 114)
and the pig one with 512 x 512

I have followed apple icon guidelines ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)) where only the 512 x 512 icon is mentioned as icon that will be used to app store. Thought they will use one of my icon files for the browsing pages but now I see that my small icon file 57x57 is a little bit small and my larger icon file 114x114 is a little bit large if compared on the screen when viewing my app icon on itunes. So, what should be the app icon size for apps browsing screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

512 x 512 is the icon displayed in iTunes. It's scaled down when browsing AppStore or Apps library, but you can see it's the large icon in iTunes' artwork view.

[image]

Comment: That scaling kills the smoothness and quality of my icon. It just looks like low quality png file. How am I supposed to guess to design that doesn't brake when scalled down? You can view my app icon, just type Green Pig in the search box.

Comment: That's a jpg icon. Are you sure you uploaded a png file?

Comment: Yep, just viewed 10 times in Xcode project dir, both icons are png crisp and sharp images

Comment: Should also note that game screens are also blurred, though uploaded high quality images. Just tried to resize those screen images manually with preview to the size they appear on the app store. The resized images with preview still remains crisp and sharp.

Comment: The icon you uploaded to iTunes Connect, doesn't matter what's in Xcode. Go to iTunes Connect/Manage Your Applications/Green Pig/View Details and under Uploads click on icon and then right click and save the image and check if it's png or jpg.

Comment: Hm, I did as you said, saved the 512x512 image from the webpage. But I'm seeing the right (png) format :(

Comment: Looks like AppStore is converting all your images to jpg for some reason. Don't know how to help you with that :( try to contact developer support.

Comment: Thanks for the try. Also, as I said my in-game screen images are blurred on app store. But they look sharp and crisp when viewed on itunes connect app manager. Try to add a review note the next version of the app.

Answer (score 1):

This post does a good job explaining all the different sizes

http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes

And yes, 512x512 is the correct size for the app store, though Apple resizes it on you.

Comment: After spending so time of releasing my first app, I got an answer that it's OK with the low quality blurry icon and blurry in-game screens. It's interesting to know what secrets the developers of Angry Birds knows that their icons are crisp and sharp and do not loose the quality when scaled down. I tried to scale icons and in-game screen images manually with Preview, looks crisp and sharp. But none of those characteristics applies to the images that are resized by app store. Am I supposed to guess the design that doesn't loos the quality when scaled by app store? :)

Comment: I'm sure there's some tricks we can use to handle Apple's scaling better.  might take some digging around though...